# How to write a program to accept a character and display its next and previous character?

Tags: python

Make use of Ascii values here.

Input:

A character

Output:

Previous character and the next character of the given character

---

Sample input:

D

Sample output:

C

E

---

Sample input:

8

Sample output:

7

9

---

Sample input:

@

Sample Output:

?

A

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post the code you're having trouble with

Comment: Tip: [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) can get the encoding of characters, and [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) can get characters according to the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `ord` and `chr` in built method

```
charcter = input()
order_input = ord(charcter)
previous_character = chr(order_input - 1)
next_character = chr(ord_input +1 )

print(f"previous character {previous_character}\n next character {next_character}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast,sys,string
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
order_input = ord(input_str)
previous_character = chr(order_input - 1)
next_character = chr(order_input +1 )
print (f" {previous_character}\n {next_character}")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks